# How to rotate AVFrame?

Tags: c++, qt, ffmpeg, libav

I'm writing an application which uses `FFMPEG` and I need a way to rotate `AVFrame`s by 90, 180 and 270 degrees since a camera could be positioned differently. I heard there're filters for doing something like that. I read `filtering_video.c` file in examples directory, but it's really hard to understand what's going on in that example. I saw `"transpose=cclock"` part of the code, which my imply that this is what I need, vut there's really not much explanation about how it works.

What is `const AVFilter *buffersrc  = avfilter_get_by_name("buffer");` and `const AVFilter *buffersink = avfilter_get_by_name("buffersink");` why do I even need those if I'm only trying to make a rotation? Why do I need `enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmts[] = { AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY8, AV_PIX_FMT_NONE };` when I don't want to change pixel formats?

Can anyone please explain how do I make `FFMPEG` rotate decoded `AVFrame`?

Answer (score 1):

| What is const AVFilter *buffersrc  = avfilter_get_by_name("buffer");

The Ffmpeg filter API is designed for a more complex use. Filters can be chained together to form a "graph", some filters have more than one input, some have more that one output. Creating a API that can support any filter type and create a link in a graph to any other possible filter means the API needs to be complex.

a "buffer" is a way into the graph, where the user can feed outside data (frames) into the graph

> and const AVFilter *buffersink = avfilter_get_by_name("buffersink");
> why do I even need those

A "buffersink" is a way to read the frames out of the graph. Without those there is no way to use the filter graph.

> Why do I need enum AVPixelFormat pix_fmts[] = { AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY8,
> AV_PIX_FMT_NONE};

Some filters can only operate on specific pixel formats, and some filters can change pixel formats. So format in may not equal the format out. Setting the pixel format can hint the graph to convert formats when necessary.

Comment: So why is there two pixel formats? Are they formats for each filter in respected order?